# React with Typescript: Type missmatch

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx-react, react-tsx

its a while started using React with typescript but always getting confused with types and what React element expects.

like in this scenario (Also [sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/6jr081w26n)) I get the follwing error for Todos Component

> in VSCODE with prettier and TSLint setup: Type '(props: PropsWithChildren) => Element[]' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent'.
>
> > in Snadbox: Type '(props: IProps) => void[]' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent'.

---

```
    import { TodoStore } from "./stores/TodoStore";
    import { observable } from "mobx";
    interface IProps {
      todoStore: TodoStore;
    }
   // red underline at `TodoComp` with mentioned error message
    const TodosComp: React.FC<IProps> = props => {
      const { todos } = props.todoStore;
      return todos.map(todo => {
        <div key={todo.id}>
          <p>{todo.title}</p>
          <select />
        </div>;
      });
    };
    export default inject("todoStore")(observer(TodosComp));
```

The Mobx store for todos is like

```
import { decorate, observable, runInAction, action } from 'mobx';
export interface ITodo {userId: number; id: number; title: string; completed: boolean;
}
export class TodoStore {
  public todos: ITodo[];
  constructor() {
    this.todos = [];
    this.fetchTodos();
  }

  public async fetchTodos() {
    const response = await fetch('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos');
    const todos: ITodo[] = await response.json();
    runInAction(() => {
      this.todos = todos;
    });
 }}
decorate<TodoStore>(TodoStore, { todos: observable, fetchTodos: action });
```

Is the problem from Mobx and if the class itself is used as a type in the component? does mobx classes need a separate interface?

Also as a Mobx specific question is the way in sandbox correct to instantiate the store class at provider?

in general, if somebody knows a good article about React with typescript how to manage props and JSX types would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function should return a JSX.Element and you need to pass a div or a Fragment, this should works.

```
const Todos: React.FC<IProps> = (props: IProps): JSX.Element => {
  const { todos } = props.todoStore;
  return (<React.Fragment>
    {todos.map(todo => {
      <div key={todo.id}>
        <p>{todo.title}</p>
        <select />
      </div>;
    })}
  </React.Fragment>);
};
```

Comment: Thanks, it was the problem. my mind just went for Mobx problem.  but just in case is my approach correct for createing new mobx state instant?

Answer (score 4):

`FunctionComponent` is defined as

```js
interface FunctionComponent<P = {}> {
  (props: PropsWithChildren<P>, context?: any): ReactElement | null;
  ...
```

where `ReactElement` is

```js
interface ReactElement<P = any, T extends string | JSXElementConstructor<any> = string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> {
  type: T;
  props: P;
  key: Key | null;
}
```

By looking at these definitions you can tell that you can't return an array from `React.FC`. The solution is to wrap your return value in react fragment like

```js
return (
  <>
    {todos.map(todo => {
      <div key={todo.id}>
        <p>{todo.title}</p>
        <select />
      </div>;
    })}
  </>
);
```